# How to search for endNodes, that are in one relationship, but not another in Neo4J Java

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a initial node of user, that can own multiple items and that items can be also organized into groups (each into multiple groups). Therefore the user can have two corresponding relationships — owning the group and owning the item. The items have an extra relationship to the groups.

I would like to find the items, that are owned by the user, but are not any group.

**Is there a way how to select these item in one traversal method, or should I get all items owned by the user and then iterate over them to find out these without the relationship to groups?**

**Edit:** I am sorry, that my question was not clear enough. By the *traversal method* I meant using the Neo4j Traversal Framework in Java. For example:

```
TraversalDescription td = db.traversalDescription()
    .breadthFirst()
    .relationships(OWNS, Direction.BOTH)
     //IS THERE A WAY HOW TO SAY THE NEXT RELATIONSHIP (EDGE) DOES NOT EXIST?
    .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition())
    .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL);

Traverser t = td.traverse(userNode);
    for (Path p : t) {
        //OR: SHOULD I LOOP TROUGH ALL THE RELATIONSHIPS OF THE END NODE - ITEM
        System.out.println(p.endNode().getProperty("name"));
    }
```

The two comments in the code are the places where I expected either a method for the `traversalDescription` or iterating through all relationships of the `endNodes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cypher:

```
MATCH (me:Person{name:'me'})-[:OWNS]->(i:Item)
WHERE NOT (i)-[:PART_OF]->()  // not part of a group
RETURN i
```

In Java API:

```
Node me = graphDb.findNode(Label.label("Person"), "name", "me");
Iterable<Relationship> owns = me.getRelationships(RelationshipType.withName("OWNS"), Direction.OUTGOING);
Stream<Node> nodes= StreamSupport.stream(owns.spliterator, false)
    .filter(r -> r.getEndNode().hasRelationship(RelationshipType.withName("PART_OF"),OUTGOING))
    .map(r -> r.getEndNode());
```